How to get offshore members to perform in a Scrum team that is co-located
I am the Product Owner on a team that has developers in UK, Poland, Italy and India.
Admittedly the team itself is slightly larger than it should be but I have seen over the past few months that those in India (developers and testers by trade) struggle with the Scrum mindset. They take no initiative and speak very little in the various events. When it comes to work, they are slow and wait to be told how to do something (even though they are all senior developers) and almost down tools at the first sign of an impediment (with no mindset to then help others) On refinement sessions, they leave everything to the non Indian members to ask and query.
When raising this with the development manager, he quotes from the Scrum playbook that the team is self-empowered and the issues should be raised in the retrospective and dealt with by the team.
I may be in the position where I am just unlucky with the quality of the team but how do other co-located teams deal with this situation? Everything I read about Scrum and offshore talks about completely offshore located teams (Indian PO and Scrum master) rather than an almost implied hierarchy with onshore, nearshore AND offshore. No matter how much we tell them there is no hierarchy and all view and opinions are equal, they are simply not buying into it or performing.

How proficient are they with English? I've heard about very similar cases where such lack of communication was in fact caused by remote workers struggling to keep up with the rest of the team language-wise: they may be able to understand the requests targeting them, but shy away from generic discussions just because they don't feel confident enough.

In India (from what I know) being a senior isnt a title you necessarily get by merit but by staying with the same company. I'd take those "senior" titles with a grain of salt.

What does the Scrum playbook say about team members who simply don't contribute?

While this is not ideal, more often than not, we all are far from being ideal. What I sense here is a lack of communication and interpersonal skills to bridge the gap.
I appreciate all your efforts so far, but in my opinion, probably a little different approach can / will help. Keeping the cultural difference in mind, if you're not doing this already - you may need to start reaching out to those team members who are not performing as expected, and coach / groom them on a 1:1 basis, instead of pointing them to the rulebooks. Provide them with a sense of ownership, and make sure they understand that their contributions are equally important for the success of the team.
Again, I do not know the internal dynamics of the team you are working with, but in my experience, sometimes people tend to open up about the problems and issues they are facing or the barriers they encounter, in a restricted environment (1:1), rather that in an open discussion (with other members present). Try talking to them, engaging them more and instead of trying to educate them, offer guidance and ask how you can be of help to avoid the issues you and team are facing because of the nature of communication (or, lack thereof).
In short, make them feel empowered, to work and to talk about work, without the consequence of being judged. Hope that will solve most of the issues, if not all.

TL;DR: help the "good" members of the team to enable the weak members
I was working as a full time scrum master in different companies for several years and twice as many years as software developer.
There are many reasons why some developers are left behind - you, as scrum master, should unveil the root cause of their problems to the team.
Some reasons for struggling are:

They do not know or understand the current code base (legacy code/bad quality/missing architecture)
They do not understand the business - even though they may be valid programmers
They lack the programming knowledge
They cannot communicate properly/they do not understand
... (many other reasons possible)

Once the root cause of their struggle is present to the whole team, the team should try to find a solution how stronger members could help the weaker members. It is important, that the team brings an solution, because they know best, what kind of help they can offer and because they can commit on helping.
Helpful tools for finding the root cause:

creating trust with Heard, Seen, Respected
finding reasons with What I need from you
9Y (nine Whys)

Helpful tools for finding support for weaker members

find a proper way to help with helping heuristic
getting at least some help started with 15% solutions

NOTE - I had many very successful Scrum Master meetings with the help from LISA - I do recommend them, because I grew a better Scrum Master with them, not because I get paid for this ^_^
